# GridView on rowdatabound , edit,delete,select options disappeared

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
string search= textbox1.text;

protected void grd_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{           
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach(TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            tc.Text = tc.Text.Replace(search, "<span style='color:Red;'>" + search + "</span>");
        }
    }            
}
```

I'm using that code to highlight a word searched but when I Debug in browser buttons:edit,select,delete are not there .and if i deleted the event the buttons are back.

what shall I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to check and see if the cell contains controls... It looks like the rest of your grid view cells just contain text and you are appending the span into the cell to highlight the search value.

```
string search= textbox1.text;

protected void grd_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{           
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach(TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (tc.Controls.Count == 0){
                tc.Text = tc.Text.Replace(search, "<span style='color:Red;'>" + search + "</span>");
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

This will bypass the cells that contain the select, edit and delete controls. And also text boxes and labels and things like that as well. Hope this helps.